# how to I select records based on the latest date

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the latest record only. It works fine if i don't include "CustFile.optin" but once I add this field, it gives me all the records. Can you please help?

```
SELECT BEST.fname, BEST.lname, BEST.email, MAX(CustFile.status_date), CustFile.optin
FROM  BEST, CustFile
WHERE BEST.email = CustFile.email
GROUP BY BEST.fname, BEST.lname, BEST.email, CustFile.optin
```

Answer:

```
fname    lname      email    optin  date
a.fname  a.lname    aa@email    y   01/08/2015
b.fname  b.lname    bb@email    n   16/06/2016
```

Comment: Can you add some `sample data set` and `expected result set`?

Comment: `fname lname email optin date
a.fname b.lname ab@email y 01/08/2015
a.fname b.lname ab@email n 04/06/2016`

Comment: I would like only the latest record but at the moment it returns all of them

Comment: Post some of your data from the database table, and don't post in comment rather add it in your question.

Comment: @ Shaharyar any suggestions please?

Comment: You have just 1 row?

Comment: What is the primary key of the `CustFile` table?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply take the row `WHERE MAX(CustFile.status_date) = CustFile.status_date`?

```
SELECT * 
FROM BEST, CustFile 
WHERE 
    BEST.email = CustFile.email AND 
    MAX(CustFile.status_date) = CustFile.status_date
```

Or order by date (desc) and take only the top most as @Paul-Spiegel says

```
SELECT * 
FROM BEST, CustFile 
WHERE BEST.email = CustFile.email
ORDER BY status_date DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: If this is what OP want, a simple `ORDER BY status_date DESC LIMIT 1` would also work.